# Perfect Square that ends in 9 distinct digits

Tags: number-theory

Determine whether there is a perfect square that ends in 9 distinct digits.

Comment: In any base or in base 10?

Comment: In base 10 only.

Comment: Take for example $(10124)^2 = 102495376$. That includes the zero. If you want only 1 to 9, the smallest one is $(11826)^2 = 139854276$. There are many many such examples. If you want a bigger one, $(34273)^2 = 1174638529$.

Answer (score 8):

Oh.... $111111111^2 =12345678987654321$

Comment: Which proves it will work for any base $\ge $ 9.

Comment: Cool!! Better than google!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is:

$$11826^2=139854276$$

Comment: How'd you find that so fast?!

Comment: Google of course :)

Comment: That's probably the smallest such perfect square.

Comment: @fleablood: Why do you think that? You may well be right, but I wouldn't be surprised to see a smaller one.

Comment: Well, Because it was googled.

Comment: I thought about cosidering the options of last digit and second to last digits.  Then this answer popped up.  It reminded me about a similar question and then I remembered  1111....^2 is 1234......4321 so that would make an *easy* answer.  So I thought about why this one googled. and I figured one could with effort figure it out by hand if one were patient and careful and then I typed the comment "It's probably the smallest.  I really don't have any reason for saying that.  sorry... stream of conciousness , really.